# Ubuntu does not recognize USB

Tags: usb, usb-drive

So guys, I was about to install Ubuntu into my USB. But recently I formatted my USB drive as FAT and clear all the data.

After that the computer doesn't recognize the USB any more. When I open nautilus it doesn't show the drive. I tried `sudo fdisk -l` :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008fcc4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   310505471   155251712   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       310507518   312580095     1036289    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       310507520   312580095     1036288   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Also a screenshot from `gnome-disks` (I plug it in but nothing changed).

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What does "fdisk -l" say?  
What do you mean with "write data to 0"?

Comment: i think he/she meant a deep format which generally turns every bit to 0. but yes, please give us the fdisk info.

Comment: P/S: My USB stick is 8GB, and i guess fdisk doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score -2):

Download and use the following program to install the `*.iso` from [here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).

Comment: This is for Windows but sorry I want it for Ubuntu.